# js how to run javascript every 2 days?

Tags: javascript, time

I have a jquery stat does something when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  tb_show('#TB_inline?height=490&width=534&inlineId=compare', false);
});
```

what I want is for the script to run *once in a while* maybe every 2 days ... any idea?

Comment: Javascript is a client side language, so a web browser would need to be ON the page for two days, but you could use setTimeout...

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context here? Is this a webpage that you expect people to stay on for more than 2 days?

Comment: @AndrewM - As much ridiculous as he made it sound, my guess is that he wants this to run if the user visited after two days' period.

Comment: But couldn't the JS find the current date and run only if the page is loaded on a Monday, or something?

Comment: what ill do is set up a cookie and look to see if is expired. the expiration will give me my time

Comment: @Christian S: Makes more sense :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a cookie to record the last time it showed up. That's document.cookie, or better still, use [jQuery's cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    var today=(new Date()).getTime();
    var two_days=1000*60*60*60*24*2;

    if($.cookie('lasttime')<today-two_days){

        // update cookie
        $.cookie('lasttime',today);

        // show popup
        tb_show('#TB_inline?height=490&width=534&inlineId=compare', false);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some element to be only shown every other day, you could do it like this, by simply using the `Date` object for getting the current day number:

```
$(function(){
    var date=new Date();
    if(date.getDate()%2){
        // Only on odd days:
        tb_show('#TB_inline?height=490&width=534&inlineId=compare', false);
    }
});
```